# Almofire and MailGun

Tags: ios, alamofire

Can anyone help with Alamofire 4? How can I convert this, I looked at the documentation and I could not figure it out. I need to authenticate but then I cannot get the response to provide information like the response, data, etc.

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/\(mgDomain)/messages", parameters:params)
        .authenticate(user: "api", password: mgKey)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            print(request)
            print(response)
            print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alamofire 4** version:

```
let url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/\(mgDomain)/messages"
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
        .authenticate(user: "api", password: mgKey)
        .response { response in
            print(response)
            print(response.request)
            print(response.error)
    }
```

Feel free to read [migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md). There are lots of examples for common requests, including your case.